# Xamarin Android - No resource found error

Tags: android, xamarin, xamarin.android, resources, android-resources

I get the following error in xamarin Android:

```
SeverityCode    Description Project File    Line    Suppression State Error     No resource found that matches the given name (at 'value' with value '@integer/google_play_services_version').
```

Please help me resolve this issue.

Comment: You tried any of this? https://forums.xamarin.com/discussion/47224/no-resource-found-that-matches-the-given-name-with-value-integer-google-play-services-version

Comment: thanks for the suggestion let me see , i am trying to make an online database for my project i have tried azure as well now i get this error using firebase......